# JavaFX Missing Title for the Stage

Tags: javafx, stage

I'm relatively new to Javafx and would like a stage that is not resizable, but also does not have the min/max buttons.  When I try the very simple test case below, when I init the style to UTILITY as well as set resizable to false, the title is not displayed.  I don't see the connection, but I have tried all the combinations of the lines below and that is what is happening.  Can anyone tell me why or what I can do to get around that (ie I would like the title, not resizable and a UTILITY stage).  I have tried this with both 1.7 and 1.8.

Thanks for the help!

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

  stage.setTitle("Test window");
  stage.setWidth(300);
  stage.setHeight(200);
  stage.setResizable(false);
  stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);

  stage.show();
}
```

Comment: I tried your example, it worked fine for me. If you init the `Stage` with `Stagestyle.UTILITY` you do not need to call `setResizable(false);` on the stage, because `Stagestyle.UTITLITY` comes with plattform decoration. On which plattform are you?

Comment: Windows 7 - not quite sure what you mean though.  I do not want the stage to be resizable, which is why I called setResizable(false).  If I don't have that line in, the operator is able to resize it.  With that line in, it behaves correctly, but I don't get the title "Test Window".  Thanks!